# How to display time value in a given string format within SSRS report?

Tags: datetime, time, format, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to Display time duration in SSRS report 
My DB field is time in SQL. It converts Timespan in SSRS.

format is :  1:00 PM - 3:50 PM

How can i do this ?

```
Fields!StartTime.Value.ToString() + " PM - "  + 
       Fields!EndTime.Value.ToString() + " PM" is not working..
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one possible way of achieving this with the help of `Custom code` in SSRS. Following example doesn't go into the details of creating SSRS reports but should give an idea of how the time formatting can be achieved within SSRS.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create a table named `dbo.Timespans` using the script provided under **SQL Scripts**. Populate it with some data as shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. Create an SSRS report and use the table `dbo.Timespans` as the data source. Refer screenshot #**2**.
3. Click on the `Report` menu and select `Report Properties`. Select the `Code` tab on the left section.
4. Paste the code given under SSRS Custom code section in the Custom code textbox. Click OK. This code takes a `timeSpan` value and `format` string. It will then format the time data and return as a string. Refer screenshot #**3**.
5. Right-click on the time column and select `Expression...` Paste the expression **`=Code.FormatTimeSpan(Fields!StartTime.Value, "hh:mm tt") + " - " +
   Code.FormatTimeSpan(Fields!EndTime.Value, "hh:mm tt")`** in the `Set expression for: Value` textbox. Refer screenshots #**4** and #**5**.
6. Screenshot #**6** shows execution of the report.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timespans](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NULL,
    [EndTime] [time](7) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Timespans] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**SSRS Custom Code:**

```
public function FormatTimeSpan(timeSpanValue as TimeSpan, format as string) as string
    Dim dateValue as DateTime
    dateValue = new DateTime(timeSpanValue.Ticks)
    return dateValue.ToString(format)
end function
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]