# Formatting dates with SQL Report Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, formatting

I'm trying to format the current date according to the generic "2012-09-04 10:20:12 AM" format but somehow the the "AM" part is always missing.

I'm using the expression `"..." & Format(CDate(Now), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")` to format the date and append it to some text. That emits the warning reproduced below but prints out the date correctly (except for the AM/PM designator).

```
[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun 
‘EmissionDate.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string 
was not in a correct format.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I'm aware of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305106/how-to-display-time-value-in-a-given-string-format-within-ssrs-report) and SQL Server query backed solutions but I'd like to use the built-in functions as much as possible.

Comment: By now I'm thinking it may have something do with the report's culture and server regional settings but I haven't figured out what yet. The regional settings have the am/pm designator defined correctly so it must be something to to with report's culture. Still have no clue about what causes the warning message, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my previous comment, the report's `Language` property was referencing a culture for which no AM/PM designator was defined. Changing it to `en-US` presented the AM/PM designator as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article and maybe it can solve your problem. I know you are already using `Format(CDate)` but since you are using `(Now)`, witch is a datetime variable, maybe you should use `FormatDateTime()` instead of `Format()`.

Try this as well:
Instead of: `Format(CDate(Now), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")` 
Use:  `Format(CDate(Now), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss am/pm")`

Link:[Working with Dates in Reporting Services](http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/04/10/working-with-dates-in-reporting-services/)

Comment: `FormatDateTime` only accepts a fixed set of formats, none of which are very interesting in my case.

Comment: I added more info try using am/pm instead of tt. Sorry if it's not working, I would test it first but I can't in my environment right now.

Comment: I had tested that already and it didn't work either. The result is something like `ax/px` where `x` is a random number in the [0-9] range (don't know why). Thanks for trying, though.